# Aligning text with image in same div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to perfectly align my text and image.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

```css
.navbar .logo a {
  color: #ececec;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.logo img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="img/favicon/favicon.png" alt="">
    <a href="#">LABFOLD</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex box to align them perfectly

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  color: #ececec;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.logo img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1280px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
  <a href="#">LABFOLD</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` to do so:

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I'd also add some right margin to the image so it's not sticking with the logo text:

```css
.logo img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```